# onPress does not redirect to screen on ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I've got a bunch of tiles (rectangles) I've created. On android it seems that when I click on the title the onPress function works as expected. But on iOS when I click the tile it doesn't work? is there something I have to do differently when it comes to onPress()?

```
   const Container = styled(BackgroundImage)`
        aspectRatio:1.32;
        alignItems:center;
        justifyContent:center;
        background: ${Colors.Black};
        borderRadius: 10px;
        width:100%;
    `
    
    const Heading = styled(TextBold)`
        color:${Colors.White};
        width:100%;
        textAlign:center;
        textAlignVertical:center;
    `
    
    const CategoryTile = (props: { venueType: VenueType, onPress: () => void }) =>
        (<Container imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10, opacity: 0.5 }} uri={props.venueType.imageUrl}>
            <Heading onPress={props.onPress} text={props.venueType.name} numberOfLines={1} />
        </Container>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out! used `<TouchableOpacity>` to fix my issue